# underdamped oscillation with quadratic decay

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I know that for a [2nd order linear differential equation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping), there are 3 possible scenarios: over-damped, critically damped and underdamped. For the underdamped case the solutions are of the form:
$e^{-\alpha t}(Acos(\omega_d t) + Bsin(\omega_d t))$

I am interested in a solution of the form $e^{-\alpha t^2}Acos(\omega_d t)$
i.e., I want the oscillations to die at quadratic rate.

Is there a corresponding differential equation that can generate this kind of behavior?

Note: I asked this question [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696613/underdamped-oscillation-with-quadratic-decay). The answer I got was a trivially constructed linear time-varying system. I am interested in a more compact and physically driven representation.

Comment: Please define "compact" and "physically driven"; that said, the oscillatory solutions take the natural form $C e^{- \alpha t + i \omega_d t}$. One should expect a quadratic version to have form $$ e^{(-\alpha + i \omega_d) t^2}$$ which would make it $\omega_d t^2$ in the $\cos$ rather than linear.

Comment: @WillieWong by physically driven I am looking for some physical analogy, i.e. maybe a nonlinear damping element.

Comment: I did not want to express the solution in polar form but yeah the oscillation is of the form $Ce^{-\alpha t + j \omega_d t}$. I do not however wish the cosine term wrt $\omega_d t^2$. I am strictly looking for standard sinusoid oscillations amplitudes of which decay according to the rate $e^{-\alpha t^2}$, i.e. quadratic rate instead of a linear one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about "physically driven", but you could try

$$\ddot{u} + 4 t \dot{u} + (4 t^2 + 3) u = 0$$

If you want something autonomous, you might make it

$$ \eqalign{\ddot{u} + 4 v \dot{u} + (4 v^2 + 3) u &= 0 \cr
       \dot{v} & = 1\cr}$$

which can be made into a single nonlinear d.e., but it will be messy.